# In RStudio/RMarkdown, how to setwd?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

`setwd` in an Rmd file in RStudio does not appear to change the directory in subsequent chunks.  Is there a way to set the working directory for good?

Example:

````
```{r}
setwd("/tmp")
getwd()
```

```{r}
getwd()
```
````

Output:

```
setwd("/tmp")
getwd()
## [1] "/private/tmp"

getwd()
## [1] "/Users/me/src"
```

This is on Mac OS 10.8.5 using RStudio 0.97.551, R version 3.0.2 and knitr version 1.5.

I wish to set the directory once for all subsequent chunks.

Comment: I think this is a `knitr` issue.  See https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/277#issuecomment-6528846 and see if it helps, though I [don't think Yihui is a fan](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/knM0VWoexT0) of globally setting `setwd`

Comment: Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538066/how-to-set-current-file-location-as-work-directory-in-r-markdown), use opts_knit rather than opts_chunk

Answer (score 51, accepted):

See [Issue #277](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/277#issuecomment-6528846) and for further background, the package author's comments [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/knM0VWoexT0)

What you are looking for is the `root.dir` option in `knitr::opts_knit`.

The following will set the root directory for subsequent code chunks (but not this chunk):

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/tmp')
```
````

### EDIT: RStudio 1.0.44

as of RStudio's latest release (Oct/Nov 2016), the following snippet is needed for knitr's `render` default:

````
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/tmp')
```
````

see Etienne's comment about versions below.

Comment: I needed to use `opts_knit` instead of `opts_chunk`

Comment: I also needed to use `opts_knit` -- may depend on whether one is using `rmarkdown::render` or `knitr::knit`, I was using the former (which is the default for RStudio's `knit HTML` button in 2016)

Comment: This works in RStudio 1.0.143 for linux, but ONLY in the ```{r setup}...``` chunk. Just calling it ```{r initialization}...``` breaks it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me: running this line followed by `getwd()` shows that it had no effect on the chunk working directory. Mac OS 10.11.6, R version 3.3.1, knitr version 1.17.

Comment: Weird... I'm in RStudio Windows 1.1.456 and it seems to want `chunk` not `knit`

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've been using, and it seems to work well when using R Projects (`.Rproj` files):

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    # This should allow Rmarkdown to locate the data
    root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file()
)
```

Comment: +1 I still had to explicitly set this via `setwd` though, so `setwd(rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())` worked. Any idea why it didnt work via your way through `knitr::opts_chunk$set`?