# Knitr / R error when saving to a relative directory

Tags: r, knitr

I try to save a variable to a relative path. The R code runs without a problem in RStudio, but as soon as I compile the RMarkdown file i get a reproducible error (only if the destination path is relative).

This is my RMarkdown file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r test}
x<-"test"
save(x,file="./raw_data/test.r")
```
````

This is the resulting error:

```
processing file: Untitled.Rmd

Quitting from lines 7-9 (Untitled.Rmd) 
Error in gzfile(file, "wb") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> save -> gzfile
Execution halted
```

Is this a bug / does knitr not support relative directory paths?

Thanks

Comment: Does the error occur if you use a tilde ~ instead of a period in the path name?

Comment: ~/ instead of ./ is incorrect, this points to the home directory. I have figured out that I can avoid the error when I use "../" for relative subdirectories in Knitr. This is equivalent to "./" in Rstudio. Unfortunately, this results in an error in the R code. So Knitr and R seem to evaluate this differently, which means that I have to adapt the R code for Knitr which defies the purpose of literate programming a bit.

Comment: Add a chunk that prints the result of `getwd()`.  You'll likely see something different than what you were expecting.  You can fix this by using `setwd()` early in the document so that the working dir is what you expect it to be.

Comment: So according to the [package author](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/knM0VWoexT0), knitr uses the location of the Rmd file as working directory and does not take into account the RStudio working dir. setwd() does not work in Knitr (see discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060518/in-rstudio-rmarkdown-how-to-setwd), I now use their recommendation ` ```{r setup}
opts_chunk$set(root.dir = '/tmp')
``` `. This works for all subsequent Knitr R code chunks.

Comment: in the next version it will be available :  https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview-release-notes/