# How to set current file location as work directory in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have mydata.RDATA to be used in R, then I need to load(), which means I need to setwd() curent directory first. I already know [how to do it in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074911/how-to-set-the-current-file-location-as-the-default-working-directory-in-r-progr).

When I do it in R markdown:

`{r echo=FALSE}
dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) 
script.dir <- dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile) 
setwd(script.dir)`

I get error as below:

`Error in dirname(parent.frame(2)$ofile) : a character vector argument expected calls :<Anonymous>...`

Comment: I really recommend using RStudio projects and relative paths. I also use the `ofile` approach in some legacy code but it is very unreliable, depending on where from the file is sourced, knitted, etc.

Comment: I use Rstudio, but never used project.I have 500+ project, then I can only store .Rdata file in each file folder.

Comment: Yes, you just have to open the project file, then the working directory is automatically set, and the files you had opend the last time in this project are opened.

Answer (score 3):

If your `.Rmd` file is in a subfolder you need to specify the root directory for knitr, *even* if you've specified a working directory with `setwd()` or even an RSudio project.

Fortunately this is as easy as adding the following chunk to the start of your `.Rmd` file, right after the YAML:

`{r "setup", include=FALSE}
require("knitr")
opts_knit$set(root.dir = "~/path/to/project")`

The `~/` is your `HOME` directory on Linux (and maybe Mac). If you're on Windows you'll have to tweak this.

Comment: I just want to neednot input '/path/to/project', because it's not flexible when your move .rmd file.

Comment: Why does it matter what you put in the chunk header? Will knitr treat a chunk differently if it's called "setup"?