# R Markdown - set the markdown file location as current directory

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm on windows 10 , RStudio 1.0.136 , R 3.3.1

I'm creating a Rmd file and want to set the location of the Rmd file as the working directory.

I looked at the related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35074911) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44538066) - but couldn't find a good solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = getwd())
```
````