# How to fix Error in setwd("D:/") when opening R

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, working-directory

I'm currently trying to Knit a file with `RStudio` and keep running into the below error:

```
Error in setwd("D:/") : cannot change working directory
Execution halted
```

However, when I check `getwd()` I get `"/Users/my-name"` as the working directory. I have also tried `setwd("~/")` and receive the same error in Markdown. Further, when I initially open `RStudio` I get

```
Error in setwd("D:/") : cannot change working directory
```

which suggests that there is an issue when I start `R`. Is there a way to get this error to stop from occurring when starting `RStudio` in the first place? I've tried deleting and redownloading `RStudio` but that doesn't seem to work. I'm currently using Mac OS Catalina.

Below is a screenshot of the error I receive when I open `RStudio`.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should change the working directory like this: ```{r setup}
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/tmp')
``` as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060518/in-rstudio-rmarkdown-how-to-setwd

Comment: It looks like I still get ```Error in setwd("D:/") : cannot change working directory Execution halted``` when trying to run ```Knit```. I'm also wondering if there is a way to stop the error from occurring when I initially open ```R```.

Comment: If you get "/Users/my-name" when you run `setwd()` that would imply that you are on a Mac. But the a path like "D:\" is something you would use on Windows. There's no such thing as a "D:\" drive on Mac. Is there code on your markdown file that tries to set the working directory explicitly? What exactly is in the file you are tying to knit. It would be helpful to see a proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MrFlick I've added a screenshot of the error when opening ```RStudio```. In terms of reproducible example, I am just trying to Knit the file initially and I think the error somehow relates to the screenshot but I don't know how that happened.

Comment: Do you have an `.Rprofile` file that automatically runs code at Startup? Does `Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")` return anything?

Comment: You were right @MrFlick. I had a ```.Rprofile``` file in my working directory. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar issue with "setwd". When I did "save as" my existing code file from other folder to a new folder then I got an error: "cannot change working directory". When I did copy a code file from other folder and paste it into a new folder then I was able to run "setwd" and there was no error.