# Accessing objects from another mardown file

Tags: variables, r-markdown, knitr, global, environment

I have generated a report using rmarkdown. I would like to generate a second report using variables I created within the first rmarkdown file. For instance, say my first document is :

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r variables, include=FALSE}
y <- 10
```

This is text.
````

Now I would like my second document to print "The value of y is 10" .  The code that doesn't work is :

```
---
output: word_document
---

The value of y is `r y`
```

How do I get access to the y variable created in my 1st document for use in my 2nd document?

Answer (score 1):

Use `knitr::knit_child()` or (equivalently) the `child` option in a chunk and set to `include = FALSE`.

`file2.Rmd`:

````
---
output: word_document
---

```{r include=FALSE}
knitr::knit_child("file1.Rmd")
```

The value of y is `r y`
````

[image]

Or `file2.Rmd` (however in this solution, text output is also displayed):

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r, child="file1.Rmd", include=FALSE}
```

The value of y is `r y`
````

---

Then `file1.Rmd`:

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r variables, include=FALSE}
y <- 10
```

This is text.
````

Comment: That is brilliant.  Many thanks Yihui.  I ended up creating an .Rda file from the first markdown file to save my variables, then loading them into the 2nd markdown file.  But this is so much easier!

Comment: I just realised that the above solution won't work for me because the output for the two .Rmd files is in different formats (html and docx respectively).  As a workaround I have created an .Rda file with the vars I require from the first .Rmd, then loading them into the 2nd .Rmd file.  It is a bit clunky but works.  I gather there is not a more concise solution if the outputs are of a different format?

Comment: Good to know. For me, the first solution (with knit_child) works on any output format. The second solution (with `child` in the chunk) results in the text from the first file being displayed as well in the second.

Comment: You are correct Mael. When I use the first solution in this example I get the correct output.   In my complicated code, I needed to add to the YAML "always_allow_html: true". Now when I run this code I get an error "Error in setwd(opts_knit$get("output.dir")) : character argument expected". The message output states that I can use "quiet=TRUE" in the chunk.  However this doesn't work.

Comment: I added Mat Dancho's solution and it worked.  No more messages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060518/in-rstudio-rmarkdown-how-to-setwd